# Custom latex handler for fenced div blocks in bookdown

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I'd like to use fenced divs in a large bookdown project to create numbered environments like Theorem, Example, etc.  Bookdown's built-in code blocks to do this aren't sufficient, since they can't have R code blocks inside of them and also interfere with RStudio syntax highlighting.
Fenced divs have a lighter syntax and work really well for me.

I can do this:

```
::: {.example #funexample}
Here is an example
:::
```

Bookdown automatically calls the lua-filter `latex-div.lua` by Lesur, Derview, and Xie on these blocks.  I've modified this filter to handle latex labels properly, and plan to continue to customize it.  I can use my new filter with the following in `output.yml`:

```
  pandoc_args:
    - --lua-filter=latex-fenced-blocks.lua
```

However, it appears that the `latex-div.lua` filter is hardwired into the `pandoc` command that bookdown uses to generate latex.  Is there a way to tell bookdown I do *not* want it to use the `latex-div.lua` filter?

The `pandoc_args` seems to only allow for adding arguments to pandoc, not removing them.

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/924 in which it seems @yihui is thinking about the same fenced div solution to theorem/example/etc. numbering.

Comment: Yes, we'll work on it in a few weeks.

Comment: @YihuiXie .. I have written a lua filter that handles fenced divs for both html and latex.  I'd like to offer it to you as a solution, or the start of a solution.  You can see it here:  https://github.com/turtlegraphics/book-test

Comment: Thanks! I don't have time to look at your Lua filer at the moment, but we have started working on our version two weeks ago: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/pull/940 Feedback welcome!